# Is there any way to synchronize an Android device with Thunderbird or any other Linux PIM application (without Google)?

Tags: sync, thunderbird, android, pim

I would like to synchronize my Android device with my desktop computer which runs Ubuntu. The following data needs to be synchronized (listed in the priority descending order):

1. Calendar
2. Tasks
3. Email
4. Contacts

The main problem is to synchronize it locally, I don't use Google Contacts or Gmail.

It is not a problem for me to switch form Thunderbird to any other opensource PIM application (e.g. Evolution).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open-source version of Zimbra has a nice mobile client - it works well with my Android smartphone (the interface is touch screen-customized). Zimbra itself has email, contacts, tasks and calendar, which are all can be viewed through the desktop and the mobile client.

Comment: this is some kind of jumping out of the frying pan into the fire...

Answer (score 2):

First I would use an IMAP mail account - provided by your own mail server or any other mail provider you trust.

Then you can set-up [Sync Kolab](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/sync-kolab/) in Thunderbird which synchronizes your contacts and calendar using a folder in the IMAP account. 
On Android side you can use the app [Kolab-android](https://code.google.com/p/kolab-android/). AFAIK it isn't available in the market therefore you have to allow 3rd party software sources and then install the apk manually.

Answer (score 1):

Funambol (formerly sync4j) seems to be an excellent project. I am just installing it now. There is a Linux server and an Android client.